# how to set data into dialog-fragment from mapActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

i m fetching lat-lang data on longclick event on my map. the problem is when i pass data in my dialog-fragment's edittext, its getting null,

here is my code of long-click event

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
     @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            if(mMap != null) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));
                double latitudeNew = point.latitude;
                double longitude = point.longitude;
                mLatLongArray.add(new double[]{latitudeNew, longitude});
                isMarkerClicked = false;

                 lat = String.valueOf(latitudeNew);
                 logt = String.valueOf(longitude);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lat,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

and i m going back using using onbackpress in my button click like this.

```
 AddGeofenceFragment.ViewHolder fragment = new AddGeofenceFragment.ViewHolder();
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if (v.getId() == R.id.btnBackToFragment) {
           String TAG = "com.rockstar.googlemap.AddGeofenceFragment";
           onBackPressed();
          // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.dialogFrgment, new AddGeofenceFragment()).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
           fragment.latitudeEditText.setText(lat);
           fragment.longitudeEditText.setText(logt);
       }
   }
```

[image]

here is my workflow, first i open my dialog-fragment on fab-button click, 
and open map for get latitude and logtitude data,

[image]

mow when i click on my "goBackTOFragment" button my app unfortunately stop, 
i dont understand wht its happening, even i get data on longclick event, i checked using toast, but its not passing to the fragment. it says null pointer exception on this line

```
 fragment.latitudeEditText.setText(lat);
 fragment.longitudeEditText.setText(logt);
```

i want to set both string data lat and logt in my previous dialog-fragment's edittext, i dont know how to pass data in fragment how do i do that. please help me. i really appreciate that.

Comment: Is the map screen new activity ?

Comment: yes, its not launcher activity.. its open when i click on dialog-fragment's map button image

Comment: You may try Fragment#setArguments().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the map activity just getting lat/lng, it could be started like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And then when you press back button (MapsActivity)

```
 Intent position = new Intent();
 position.putExtra("lat", lat);
 position.putExtra("lng", lng);
 setResult(1, position );     
 finish();
```

Again your first activity, you received position from map. U can use dialog fragment's fields. In your case, you losing dialog fragment instance.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == 1){
        double lat =  intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", -1);
        double lng =  intent.getDoubleExtra("lng", -1);
    }

}
```

I think, this approach better for your case. Also you can check deeply from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/intents/result.html)

**EDIT**

I also saw your latest update on the question post.

```
AddGeofenceFragment.ViewHolder fragment = new AddGeofenceFragment.ViewHolder();

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
    fragment.latitudeEditText.setText(lat);
    fragment.longitudeEditText.setText(logt);
}
```

This wrong, with this usage, you just instantiating, not calling onCreateView method of DialogFragment. Check this below

In first activity, i'm calling AddGeofenceFragment first time. Also keeping fragment instance for later usage.

```
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  AddGeofenceFragment dialogInstance = new AddGeofenceFragment();
  AddGeofenceFragment.show(fm, "AddGeofenceFragment");
```

In Maps activity, I choose position.

```
 public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
     Intent position = new Intent();
     position.putExtra("lat", point.latitude);
     position.putExtra("lng", point.longitude);
     setResult(1, position );     
     finish();
 }
```

In first activity, i'm getting the position

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == 1){
        double lat =  intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", -1);
        double lng =  intent.getDoubleExtra("lng", -1);
        dialogInstance.latitudeEditText.setText(lat);
        dialogInstance.longitudeEditText.setText(lng); 
    }

}
```

Comment: there is a problem my dialog going to dismiss and i cant store data in edittext

Comment: Yeah because you were losing dialog fragment. In this approach it shouldn't happen

Comment: then how can store data in dialog-box edittext.. is there any solution?

Comment: In onActivityResult,  u can use dialog fragment's fields.

Comment: can you tell me why you used -1 in onActivityResult

Comment: Why used 1 : Also used in setResult(1, position ); 
Its just an unique request code, to know getting right response when onActivityResult triggered.

Comment: i talking about minus -1,

Comment: thanks though, its very useful code.. i m up your answer, its working now. i got my solution

Comment: Your welcome.
By the way, minus -1 is just default value for getDoubleExtra

Answer (score 0):

Main activity and fragment should communicate over interface callbacks. They generally has no common memory to share directly. See http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html